# How can I get polynomial $p(x)$?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

$p(x)$ is divided evenly into $x^{2}+1$, and $p(x)+1$ is divided evenly into $x^{3}+x^{2}+1$. How can I get $p(x)$?

Comment: do you mean $p(x)=x^{3}+x^{2}$? It isnt divided evenly into $x^{2}+1$

Comment: are you studying Bezout's lemma? just apply its proof as the two polynomials are coprime and you should be done.

Answer (score 2):

The given data tells us:

$$\begin{align}r(x)(x^2 + 1) &= p(x)\\
s(x)(x^3 + x^2 + 1) &= p(x) + 1
\end{align}$$

The above equations imply that

$$s(x)(x^3 + x^2 + 1) - r(x)(x^2 + 1) = 1. \tag1$$

Does the structure of the equation ring any bells? Yes! Bezout's identity!

Now use [Euclid's division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity) on $x^2 + 1$ and $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ to obtain:

$$x(x^3 + x^2 + 1) - (x^2 + x - 1)(x^2 + 1) = 1\tag2$$

Compare (1) and (2) and eventually get $p(x)$.